# Hover com scale somente na div pai

Tags: html, sass, css-hover

pessoal seguinte possuo uma `div` pai e dentro dela outras `divs` eu queria aplicar um `css` onde mudasse o fundo para roxo e os textos e imagem para branco até ai funciona normal o problema é que queria aplicar um `scale` no fundo que ficou roxo com o `:hover` mais fazendo isso ele aplica o efeito de `:hover` nos demais elementos e nesse caso queria que o efeito de `scale` ficasse somente no fundo. segue meu código:

OBS estou usando SASS anexei uma imagem para mostrar o resultado final.

SASS

```
.box-courses{
    border: 2px solid $gray-light;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    @include transition(.5s);

    &:hover{
      @include gradient-bg(gradient);
      @include box-shadow(shadow);
      @include scale(1.1);
      border: none; 
      .title-course{
         @include scale(1);
        color: $white;
      }

      .icon-course{
         @include scale(1);
        background-image: url(../images/courses/html-hover.png);
      }

      .description{
         @include scale(1);
        color: $white;
      }
    }

    .title-course{
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;  
      color: $gray;
    }

    .icon-course{
      background-image: url(../images/courses/html.png);
      width: 52px;
      height: 57px;
    }

    .description{
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    .buttons{
      margin-top: 15px;
      li{
        .btn-custom{
          padding: 10px 15px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="box-courses">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                            <div class="icon-course"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <h4 class="title-course">Curso de HTML5: Aprenda de maneira descomplicada.</h4>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p class="description">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled buttons">
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn-gradient btn-custom">Saiba mais</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn-white btn-custom"><span>Comprar curso agora</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

o layout
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu código percebam aqui que a font e os demais elementos aumentaram e não é isso que eu quero só quero aumentar o fundo roxo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem uma técnica que enquanto vc faz o **Scale Up no Pai** ao mesmo tempo vc faz um **Scale Down no filho**. *(não vou fazer com o seu SASS pq não tenho compilador).* Ma segue um exemplo prático.

Esse exemplo pode te ajudar a entender o conceito da técnica.

```css
.box-courses {
    background-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
.box-courses:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.box-courses .small{
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.box-courses:hover .small{
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box-courses">
                <div class="small">
                    <h1>gdfg</h1>
                    <img src='http://placeskull.com/80/80' alt=''/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem um problema matemático aí. 0.9 não é o "oposto" de 1.1 - Se aumentou 1.1, o inverso é 0.90909090909... (outro exemplo: se você aumentar um valor em 25%, tem que diminuir apenas 20% para ele voltar ao original)

Comment: @Bacco xD verdade! Só não sei se confere, mas esses dias ouvi falar que o CSS só entende até 4 casas decimais, 0,0001 depois disso ele ignora....

Comment: @Bacco já até achei uma referencia, a quantidade das casas decimais faria de Browser para Browser. Acho que vou até fazer uma pergunta sobre isso para deixar registrado no site olha ai http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/